# Making silent function non silent in vim

Tags: vim, scripting

I use the the [template-file-loader](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=198) vim script to load a template file when I create p.x. a new latex file.

The template-file-loader script is able to execute a custom TemplateFileFunction_tex when I edit a new tex file..

```
fun! TemplateFileFunc_tex()
    let tex_templates = "$HOME/.vim/templates/tex/"
    let choice = confirm("Which template should i load", 
                \ "&presentation\n" .
                \ "&hd-presentation\n" .
                \ "&paper\n" .
                \ "hd-pape&r\n" .
                \ "&xelatex-default\n")
    if choice == 1 " presentation
        execute "0r "  . expand(tex_templates . "presentation.tex")
" [...]
endfun
```

The problem is the template-file-loader plugins calls the function with silent.

How do I without "unsilent" my custom function without changing the plugin?

Comment: Ok I found the unsilent function in vim, but I don't see how to use it with the confirm function. Just writing "unsilent confirm" does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to make `confirm` receive user input in silenced mode. But you can use `getchar` instead:

```
let variants=['&presentation', '&hd-presentation', ...]
echohl MoreMsg
unsilent echo "Which template should I load\n".join(variants, "\n")
echohl None
let reply=getchar()
if type(reply)==type(0)
    let reply=nr2char(reply)
endif
if reply is# "\n"
    let choice=1
else
    let replkeys=map(copy(variants), 'tolower(v:val[stridx(v:val, "&")+1])')
    let choice=index(replkeys, reply)+1
endif
if choice==1
    ...
```

Comment: Recieving user input is not the problem. When I enter the appropriate character the choice get's the correct user input. **Unsilent echo** is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. I can just echo the possible choices before the choice. That seems to be the easiest way for me.

Comment: @Kungi On my system `silent unsilent echo confirm("Description\n&choice1\nc&hoice2\n")` ignored every input except `<CR>` (and `O`, but I failed to test it), while still showing the prompt, I guessed that this is the problem (I now reread help and realized that I should have written `silent unsilent echo confirm("Description", "&choice1\nc&hoice2")`). In the last variant confirm works normally. I have not tested this in a function though.

Comment: Hmm the last one works but I don't get how to wrap it into a function, since I'm not echoing the value. when I try something like this: `let choice = unsilent confirm(...)` it does not print out anything. So I will stick wich `echo "Choices"; let choice = confirm(...)`. This somewhat defeats the purpose of confirm but works for me :-).

Comment: @Kungi. Why not `unsilent let`? I would never write `unsilent confirm()` because `unsilent` is a command that accepts another command and `confirm()` is an expression. When you write vim scripts you should know where you use commands and where expressions, it is strange that I sometimes see people mistaking them. `silent unsilent let var=confirm(...)` works for me.

Comment: Because I did not know I can use unsilent in combination with let :-). I don't write vim scripts, I just try to use them. But thank you very much for that explanation. This makes things much clearer

Answer (score 0):

This is another template-expander, but still, [mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate) handles correctly questions to the end-user. e.g.

```
VimL: " @file {rtp}/templates/tex.template

VimL: " way 1:
VimL: " instructions continued on several lines are not supported
VimL: let s:tex_kind = CONFIRM("Which template should i load", "&presentation\n&hd-presentation\n&paper\nhd-pape&r\n&xelatex-default\n", 1)
VimL: " include {rtp}/templates/tex/internals/presentation.template ?
VimL: if s:tex_kind == 1  | call s:Include('presentation', 'tex/internals') | endif
VimL: " include {rtp}/templates/tex/internals/hd-presentation.template ?
VimL: if s:tex_kind == 2  | call s:Include('hd-presentation', 'tex/internals') | endif
...

VimL: " Way 2
VimL: let s:tex_kind = WHICH("CONFIRM", "Which template should i load", "&presentation\n&hd-presentation\n&paper\nhd-pape&r\n&xelatex-default\n", 1)
VimL: let s:tex_kind = substitute(s:tex_kind, '&', '', 'g')
VimL: call s:Include(s:tex_kind, 'tex/internals')
```